# Get page content from URL?

Tags: java, url

I want to get content of page from URL by this code :

```
public static String getContentResult(URL url) throws IOException{

    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    byte [] buffer = new byte[256];

    while(true){
        int byteRead = in.read(buffer);
        if(byteRead == -1)
            break;
        for(int i = 0; i < byteRead; i++){
            sb.append((char)buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

But with this URL : http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=152610.152611&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=114782066&CFTOKEN=85539315
 i can't get Asbtract :Database management systems will continue to manage.....

Can you give me solution for solve problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255730/java-retrieve-html-page-in-proper-encoding

Comment: @Matt Ball the problem here is that the OP needs JavaScript to execute in order to get desired content, and in that sense the question is fundamentally different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outputting the header of of the get request:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 18 Nov 2010 15:35:24 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
location: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=152610.152611&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This means that the server wants you to download the new locations address. So either you get the header directly from the UrlConnection and follow that link or you use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) automatically which automatically follow redirects. The code below is based on [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/):

```
public class HttpTest {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(readPage(new URL("http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=152610.152611&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=114782066&CFTOKEN=85539315")));
    }

    private static String readPage(URL url) throws Exception {

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            {
                int read;
                char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
                while ((read = reader.read(cbuf)) != -1)
                    sb.append(cbuf, 0, read);
            }

            return sb.toString();

        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you recomen me which lib use for this code because i can't run it with httpcore from apache !

Comment: I can run your code ! But the result same with my code ? could you give any suggestion

Comment: @tiendv: I just tried this code and I get the redirected page as expected, what are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "Database management..." on given url. Perhaps, it's loaded by javascript dynamically. You'll need to have more sophisticated application to download such content ;)

Answer (score 0):

The content you're looking for is not included in this URL. Open your browser and view the source code. Instead many javascript files are loaded. I think the content is fetched later by AJAX calls. You would need to learn how the content is loaded.

The Firfox Plugin Firebug could be helpful for a more detaild analyse.

Answer (score 0):

The url that you should be using is:

```
http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=152610.152611&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE
```

Because the original url you posted (as mentioned by dacwe) sends redirect.